# Rails controller wrong template location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I have a model, controller and routes configured sucessfully with the name animegif.

In my show method, it looks under application/show instead of `views/animegif/show`.

> Missing template animegif/show, application/show
>    "searched in /Users/myName/Desktop/testapp/app/views

My easy fix was adding this method to my animegif controller but I do not understand why is it not searching under `views/animegif/show` by default.

When I followed the rails tutorial by Michael Hartl, the paths were located correctly. Is there something I am doing wrongly?

Name of controller: animegifs_controller, model: animegif

For my routes I am using resources to generate the default routes for the model

```
 def self.controller_path
     "animegif"
  end
```

Comment: can you provide your controller and routes code?

Comment: From the error it gave you, it does seem to look in `app/views` . By the looks of it, it's not finding the show page. Make sure it's named correctly. Like `show.html.erb` or if you use something like SLIM or HAML for templating `show.html.slim` / `show.html.haml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the error message once again you can see it first `animegif/show` directory of your views. If rails does not find the required template in that directory then it falls back to `app/views`. You are only getting this error message because either the `show.html.erb` is not there or you have any typo error.

If you are more curious about how rails finds your views, please refer to [this post by Andy Wang.](http://climber2002.github.io/blog/2015/04/06/digging-rails-how-rails-finds-your-templates-part-4/) He has explained it in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error message it is looking in `app/views/animegif/` and `app/views/application/` but cannot find the template. So you probably have a typo in the template's name `show.html.erb` (or other formats than html) in the respective directory.